# Force a specific version for a dependency when using dep

Tags: go, dependencies, dependency-management

I am using *dep* to manage the dependencies of a Go tool I'm writing.

This tool uses https://github.com/desertbit/grumble as an dependency. This in turn uses https://github.com/chzyer/readline as a dependency. The problem is that when trying to run my tool I get the following error:

`vendor/github.com/desertbit/grumble/app.go:295:20: unknown field 'HistorySearchFold' in struct literal of type readline.Config`

I know why this is happending. *grumble* uses the *master* branch of *readline* as a dependency. In this the field `HistorySearchFold` is available.
When using `dep init`/`dep ensure` not the *master* but the *1.4* tag is pulled into the vendor folder.

My question therefore is: How can I force *dep* to pull the *master* branch instead?

I tried adding the following in my Gopkg.toml file:

```
[[constraint]]
  branch = "master"
  name = "github.com/chzyer/readline"
```

Sadly this is not working. When I check the version pulled into the vendor folder it is still *1.4*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are trying to control the version of a transient dependency (not one directly used by your package, you should use the [`[[override]]` directive](https://github.com/golang/dep/blob/master/docs/Gopkg.toml.md#override)

It looks exactly the same as a constraint, but it will constrain dependencies even when not directly inherited by your package.

```
[[override]]
  branch = "master"
  name = "github.com/chzyer/readline"
```

Note that this is also useful for when the dependency solver finds conflicting dependencies, e.g. your package P makes use of packages A and B, and both depend on different versions of package X... you can use an override on package X inside of your package P

Comment: Worked exactly as you described. Thank you.